# Is there a way to check if the pointer has a faulty value?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, pointers, null

So me and people here have reached the conclusion that the variable probably contains a faulty value, I was asked to post the rest of the code, however my question was not meant to be how to fix my code(its quite enourmous anyway) but if I can do a check for faulty value that is not null(if there is such thing in c)

```
char *s;
    s = search(arr1[0], arr2[0]);
```

this never happens

```
 if(s==NULL) printf("Not found");
```

yet this crashes the console if NULL was meant to be returned

```
 strlen(s)
```

here is the code

```
typedef struct PERSON {
    char name[25];
    char surname[36];
    char rnum[11];
    char adress[50];
} PERSON;

int compare2(const void* kl, const void* oso) {
    PERSON* par = (PERSON*)oso;
    char key1[60];
    strncpy_s(key1, 35, par->surname, 35);
    strncat_s(key1, 24, par->name, 24);
    return strcmp((const char*)kl, (const char*)key1);
}



   char* search(const char* jm, const char* pr) {
        char key[60];
        PERSON* pom;
        strncpy_s(key, 60, pr, 35);
        strncat_s(key, 60, jm, 24);
        pom = (PERSON*)bsearch(key, registr, countPerson, sizeof(PERSON), compare2);
        return pom->rnum;
```

to show everyone what the solution is clearly for display, here is it

```
  char* search(const char* jm, const char* pr) {
        char key[60];
        PERSON* pom;
        strncpy_s(key, 60, pr, 35);
        strncat_s(key, 60, jm, 24);
        pom = (PERSON*)bsearch(key, registr, countPerson, sizeof(PERSON), compare2);
if (!pom)
        return NULL;
    else
return pom->rnum;
```

Comment: Show complete code.  Are you calling `strlen(s)` when s is NULL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @WilliamPursell I used strlen even after a NULL check and it still crashed

Comment: Yes, if `s == NULL` and you call `strlen(s)`, you will get an error.  That is expected.

Comment: @WilliamPursell to repeat myself I use if(s != NULL)strlen(s) and it still crashes thats why the question name if you read it

Comment: Allow me to also repeat myself: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're going to have to show your search function. I think that's where the problem will be found. Without that it's hard to say what the issue is.

Comment: I believe this question should be reopened because those who closed it down dont understand how large my code is and that its been made by different people(ive been told to not post large codes before) and that my question was more directed towards What is this third possibility that is happening, and what can I do about it(check for it?) which I made more clear in my latest edit, also there arent many questions on this topic upon searching, so this would benefit all those curious

Comment: Added the requestion function @breakthatbass

Comment: There are lots of issues in that code. What's the definition of struct Person? `bsearch()` looks for a `Person` in an array of `Person`.  `const void *k1` will be of type `struct Person *`, not `const char *`. Does the compiler warn about anything?

Comment: nope, no warning, and yeah thats the issue of the code, all of it is interconnected
struct person has 4 strings, name, surname,rnum, adress and countPerson is number of people
all the data loads from a file which has like 4 other functions for it to load and save properly, again not made by me and was told not to worry about them @JackLilhammers

Comment: "_nope, no warning_" -- are compiler warnings turned up? Don't rely on default settings; use something like `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` at a minimum.

Comment: I tried to fix your code to at least make your intent understandable. Maybe you could use my edits and see if it gets better...

Comment: @adabsurdum I didn't want to answer the question with my edit. I tried to make an adjustment towards the minimal reproducible example. Anyway you can revert that change and I'll put it in my answer if it's better

Comment: @adabsurdum well, it would have been implicit even if I didn't say it, but I get it. I should have suggest the changes in my answer or in chat. Rolling back is fair :)

Comment: Now it is always NULL, it never find said name or surname @JackLilhammers

Comment: Okay thank you for @JackLilhammers , while your edit made my code fail everytime your check for NULL at pom and returning NULL did help, cant believe I didnt try that myself, I think I did the check but what really fixed everything for me, was RETURNING NULL (from the limited knowledge i have i suppose the null would still happen but as it would travel down the functions throught pointers, that clear NULL would then degrade to some undefined value causing errors) thanks to everyone who stayed here and helped me

Comment: You're welcome. The next time work a little harder on your question and in providing some code that we can actually run to reproduce your issue :)

Comment: `those who closed it down dont understand how large my code is` that's why people told you to make a [mcve]. Do you understand minimal means? Read every line of that and also http://sscce.org/ carefully. That helps you solve the problem and also helps you ask a question when you're stuck

Answer (score 1):

*I'm writing an answer for code readability*

The fact that `s != NULL` doesn't mean much.
**`s` could have a faulty value, be `!= NULL`, and still cause your crash.**
I've tried to write something out to help the OP in providing a minimal reproducible example, **but this code is not meant to work**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct PERSON {
    char name[60];
    char surname[60];
    char rnum[60];
    char adress[60];
} PERSON;

int compare2(const void* kl, const void* oso) {
    PERSON *par = (PERSON*)oso;
    PERSON *key = (PERSON*)kl;
    int cmp;

    cmp = strcmp(par->surname, key->surname);
    if (cmp)
        return cmp;
    else
        return strcmp(par->name, key->name);
}

char *search(const char* jm, const char* pr) {
    PERSON key;
    PERSON *pom;
    strncpy_s(key.surname, 60, pr, 35);
    strncpy_s(key.name, 60, jm, 24);
    pom = (PERSON*)bsearch(&key, registr, countPerson, sizeof(PERSON), compare2);
    if (!pom)
        return NULL;
    return pom->rnum;
}

int main()
{
    char *arr1[2] = { "arr1[0]", "arr1[1]" };
    char *arr2[2] = { "arr1[0]", "arr1[1]" };
    char *str = search(arr1[0], arr2[0]);
    
    if (str == NULL)
        printf("Not found\n");
    else
        printf("strlen(%s): %lu\n", str, strlen(str));
}
```

Comment: Hey is there a way how I could check for the faulty value like one checks for null? @Jack Lilhammers

Comment: Not that I know of. I mean the value of a pointer is just an address, and if it's `!= NULL` and the type is correct, it's up to the programmer

Comment: Your question wasn't bad, but if you don't post the code of the `search()` function it's really hard to help you

Comment: alright i added in the requested search function @Jack Lilhammers